# Can't change the background color of MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having some issues changing the background color of my dialog components, and have exhausted all the answers from similar posts here on stackoverflow.

In styles.scss i have the following class:

```
.dialog-panel {
    background: red !important;
}
```

And I open my using this class:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateOrEditTaskDialogComponent, {
    panelClass: 'dialog-panel'
});
```

The problem is that upon opening the dialog it is red but within less than a second it fades back to default. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKqcF.png) right after opening the dialog:

And here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoGcY.png) of the dialog after the red had "faded". If you look closely you can even see the red background in the corners because of the border radius.

It looks like it might be "mat-mdc-dialog-surface mdc-dialog__surface" that is surfacing on top? But I could not find much about this online.

--EDIT--
I made this example that shows the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kejni3?file=src%2Findex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may access dialog surface property from global-styles.css

```
.dialog-panel
  .mat-mdc-dialog-container
  .mdc-dialog__container
  .mat-mdc-dialog-surface {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ar7rmf?file=src/global_styles.css) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it like this:

```
.dialog-panel > mat-dialog-container{
  background-color: red;
}
```

this will change the color of the dialog. if you have a div in you dialog and it has color, you should customize its color too.

Comment: I just tried that, it sadly behaves the exact same as what I posted originally.

Comment: don't you have any other background colors in you component?

Comment: I am, but none are are white. I just tried removing them and I still experience the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite Material Web Component CSS var in charge of colouring dialog container.

You can do that directly in your custom panel class

```css
.custom-dialog-panel {
  --mdc-dialog-container-color: red;
}
```

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateOrEditTaskDialogComponent, {
    panelClass: 'custom-dialog-panel'
});
```